# Django-Rest-Framework. Updating two tables

Tags: django

I'm having a problem of updating a nested object.
So I have two models which structure is similar to this one:

```
class EmployeeEvent(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
start_date = models.DateField()
end_date = models.DateField()


class EmployeeEvent_Users(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
employee_event = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeEvent, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='employee_event_employee_list')

employee = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employeeEvent_employee')
```

I've wrote the following serializers:

```
class EmployeeEventUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = EmployeeEvent_Users
    fields = ('id', 'employee',)

class EmployeeEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
employee_event_users = EmployeeEventUserSerializer( required=True, many=True)

class Meta:
    model = EmployeeEvent
    fields = ('event_name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'employee_event_users', )

def create(self, validated_data):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    employee_event = EmployeeEvent.objects.create(
        event_name=validated_data['event_name'],
        start_date=validated_data['start_date'],
        end_date=validated_data['end_date'],
        # etc ...
    )
    employeeEventUsers_data = validated_data.pop('employee_event_users', [])

    for employeeEventUser_data in employeeEventUsers_data:
        employeeEvent_users = EmployeeEvent_Users.objects.create(
            employee_event=employee_event,
            employee=employeeEventUser_data['employee'],

        )
    employee_event.employee_event_users = employeeEventUsers_data;
    return employee_event


def update(self, instance, validated_data):

    instance.event_name = validated_data['event_name']
    instance.start_date = validated_data['start_date']
    instance.end_date = validated_data['end_date']
    instance.save()

    instance.employee_event_users = validated_data.get('employee_event_users')


    if instance.employee_event_users:
        for employee_event_user in instance.employee_event_users:
            employee_event_user_id = employee_event_user.get('employee_id', None)
            if employee_event_user_id:
                emp_user = EmployeeEvent_Users.objects.get(id=employee_event_user_id, employee_event=instance)
                emp_user.employee = employee_event_user.get('employee', emp_user.employee)
                emp_user.save()
            else:
                EmployeeEvent_Users.objects.create(employee_event=instance, **employee_event_user)

    return instance
```

Till now, the create works perfectly and update is not working. EmployeeEvent table is updating correctly but not updating EmployeeEvent_User table. I think the below logic is correct, but it misses something. Any help would be really appreciated. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

See if this update method works any better for you:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.event_name = validated_data['event_name']
    instance.start_date = validated_data['start_date']
    instance.end_date = validated_data['end_date']

    # When updating children, I find it easier to delete them all
    # and then re-add them instead of checking each one. It probably
    # is not very efficient, however for small lists it should not
    # matter much.
    for emp in instance.employee_event_users.all():
      emp.delete()

    # Now go through and re-add the EmployeeEvent_User
    for employee_event_user in validated_data['employee_event_users']:
        user = EmployeeEvent_Users.objects.create(employee_event=instance, **employee_event_user)
        instance.employee_event_users.add(user)

    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Two things to note: I moved the `instance.save()` to the end. In your test case you were saving your instance before adding/editing your employees. Second, in your test case, you were assigning a dictionary-type object to your `employee_event_users` and not actual objects that it expected. You can modify your test case, where you create the new user, to add it to the list and then save (if you do not want to delete the children and then re-add them). Here's what that would look like:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.event_name = validated_data['event_name']
    instance.start_date = validated_data['start_date']
    instance.end_date = validated_data['end_date']

    for employee_event_user in validated_data['employee_event_users']:
        employee_event_user_id = employee_event_user.get('employee_id', None)
        if employee_event_user_id:
            emp_user = EmployeeEvent_Users.objects.get(id=employee_event_user_id, employee_event=instance)
            emp_user.employee = employee_event_user.get('employee', emp_user.employee)
            emp_user.save()
        else:
            user = EmployeeEvent_Users.objects.create(employee_event=instance, **employee_event_user)
            user.save()
            instance.employee_event_users.add(user)

    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: While trying the above code, I am getting an error
"'EmployeeEvent' object has no attribute 'employee_event_users' ".
Any solution?

Comment: Yes, in your `serializers.py` replace `employee_event_users ` with `employeeEvent_employee`. I *think* that will solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky way of doing it but it works.  Probably NOT a clean solution.

```
@api_view(('PATCH',))
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated, ])
def update_employer_profile(request):

    user_id = request.user.id

    request.data._mutable = True
    request.data['employer_user'] = user_id

    # Employer Details Table
    database_row_1 = TblEmployerDetails.objects.get(
        employer_user=user_id)

    employer_details_serialiser = TblEmployerDetailsSerializer(
        instance=database_row_1, data=request.data)


    user_serializer = UserSerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)


    # User Table
    if user_serializer.is_valid():
        user_serializer.save()

        # Employer Details Table
        if employer_details_serialiser.is_valid():
            employer_details_serialiser.save()

            updated = {**employer_details_serialiser.data, **user_serializer.data}

            return Response(updated, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            return Response(employer_details_serialiser.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    else:
        return Response(user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: The http statuses can be updated as per your requirements :)